# Specify specific bean to be injected from specific configuration class

Tags: java, spring

I am having one problem where bean definition for a single Service are defined in 2 different configuration classes.

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationA{
   @Primary
   @Bean("beana")
   public beanA(){
         return Mockito.mock(BeanA.class);
   }
   @Bean("beanb")
   public beanB(){
         return new BeanB(beanA());
   }

   @PostConstruct
   public void initialize(){
        beanA().dosomething();
   }
}

@Configuration
public class ConfigurationB{
   @Bean("beana")
   public beanA(){
          return new BeanA();
   }         
}
```

So when intialize() method is called, I am expecting mocked instance of BeanA will be used but its using real instance that is injected via ConfigurationB class.

I have marked "beana" as primary bean so spring should Ideally use this instance but its using the actual real instance defined in different configuration class.

Is there any way we can configure to use the bean definition from ConfigurationA class instead of ConfigurationB?

Comment: Are these configurations under your control? Do you actually need both beans at the same time? What's the purpose of having both?

Comment: ConfigurationA is test configuration and it imports some dependent Configurations via which internally ConfigurationB is also imported. Now in both these configuration classes, same bean name is given. But one of them is marked as primary so I am expecting that primary bean to be used.